# How to move login box to the right side?

Tags: html, css

I created a html login box and designed it, the problem is the login box is stuck on the left side of the screen. I've tried to shift it to the right but my methods have failed. Wondering if there's a simple solution to the issue or if maybe I added too many elements that are affecting it?

Example:

```css
   .loginbox {
  width: 320px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.avatar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -50%;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.loginbox p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.loginbox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.loginbox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fb2525;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointed;
  background: #ffc107;
  color: #000;
}

.loginbox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.loginbox a:hover {
  color: #ffc107;
}

.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Login Form Starts -->
<div class="loginbox">
  <img src="https://cdn.houseplansservices.com/product/scne5s9p1kk12soorouhkn56dt/w800x533.jpg?v=18" alt="avatar" class="responsive">
  <h2>Login Here</h2>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <input action="RoyalReaderHomePageL.php" type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login">
    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a><br>
    <a href="signup.php">Not a member? Sign up Now</a>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- Login Form Ends -->
```

I tried to shift it to the left via changing the margin and adding padding but that method failed.

Comment: try `img{float:left;}`. that would solve your problem.

Comment: `.avatar {` does not exist

Comment: use margin: 0 0 auto auto in the css property of .loginbox.

Answer (score 2):

Try using, css on your main div i.e..loginbox
as float: right

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Add `float: right;` to  `.loginbox` in CSS:

```
   .loginbox {
  width: 320px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  float: right;
}
```

```css
.loginbox {
  width: 320px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  float: right;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.avatar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -50%;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.loginbox p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.loginbox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.loginbox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fb2525;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointed;
  background: #ffc107;
  color: #000;
}

.loginbox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.loginbox a:hover {
  color: #ffc107;
}

.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Login Form Starts -->
<div class="loginbox">
  <img src="https://cdn.houseplansservices.com/product/scne5s9p1kk12soorouhkn56dt/w800x533.jpg?v=18" alt="avatar" class="responsive">
  <h2>Login Here</h2>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <input action="RoyalReaderHomePageL.php" type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login">
    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a><br>
    <a href="signup.php">Not a member? Sign up Now</a>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- Login Form Ends -->
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your loginbox and assign the wrapper display flex you can push with justify-content: end; the box to the right.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}

.loginbox {
  width: 320px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.avatar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -50%;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.loginbox p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.loginbox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.loginbox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fb2525;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointed;
  background: #ffc107;
  color: #000;
}

.loginbox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.loginbox a:hover {
  color: #ffc107;
}

.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Login Form Starts -->
  <div class="loginbox">
    <img src="https://cdn.houseplansservices.com/product/scne5s9p1kk12soorouhkn56dt/w800x533.jpg?v=18" alt="avatar" class="responsive">
    <h2>Login Here</h2>
    <form>
      <p>Username</p>
      <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Enter Username">
      <p>Password</p>
      <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password">
      <input action="RoyalReaderHomePageL.php" type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login">
      <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a><br>
      <a href="signup.php">Not a member? Sign up Now</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Login Form Ends -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `margin-left: auto;` and `disply: block;` to the *loginbox* div

```css
.loginbox {
  width: 320px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.avatar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -50%;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.loginbox p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.loginbox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.loginbox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fb2525;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointed;
  background: #ffc107;
  color: #000;
}

.loginbox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.loginbox a:hover {
  color: #ffc107;
}

.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Login Form Starts -->
<div class="loginbox">
  <img src="https://cdn.houseplansservices.com/product/scne5s9p1kk12soorouhkn56dt/w800x533.jpg?v=18" alt="avatar" class="responsive">
  <h2>Login Here</h2>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <input action="RoyalReaderHomePageL.php" type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login">
    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a><br>
    <a href="signup.php">Not a member? Sign up Now</a>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- Login Form Ends -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly unclear on your desire but perhaps put it in a 1 X 2 grid.

```css
.loginbox {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(400px, auto) / 1fr;
  width: 320px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

h2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

form {
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
}

.avatar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -50%;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.loginbox p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.loginbox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.loginbox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fb2525;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointed;
  background: #ffc107;
  color: #000;
}

.loginbox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.loginbox a:hover {
  color: #ffc107;
}

.responsive {
  grid: 1 / 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">
  <img src="https://cdn.houseplansservices.com/product/scne5s9p1kk12soorouhkn56dt/w800x533.jpg?v=18" alt="avatar" class="avatar responsive">
  <h2>Login Here</h2>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <input action="RoyalReaderHomePageL.php" type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login">
    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a><br>
    <a href="signup.php">Not a member? Sign up Now</a>
  </form>
</div>
```